# How can I know why a program causes a coredump sigfault?

Tags: c

I have those functions and I would like to know if anyone can help me. I have to investigate why they cause a "segfault", and why it happens faster or slower depending on its conditions.
I supposed that in Rec1, it's caused by an infinite loop that collapses the memory of the memory stack. In rec2 I suppose it's caused faster because of the same condition that in Rec1 but adding that it is allocating memory everytime for the pointer too.
In Rec3 () that crashes instantly because it's allocating the same memory spot in the second iteration and causes a problem because the program is trying to access the same allocated memory.
In Rec4 () I think it's caused because it creates an array with infinite positions, ask is the limiting of the array max space.
Can you give me some advices on those suppositions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MOD 10000

int k = 0;

char global[100];

void
panic (char *m)
{
  fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", m);
  exit (0);
}

void
rec1 ()
{
  k++;
  if (k % MOD == 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k / MOD);
  rec1 ();
}

void
rec2 ()
{
  int *tmp;

  tmp = malloc (100 * sizeof (int));
  if (tmp == NULL)
    exit (0);

  k++;
  if (k % MOD == 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k / MOD);
  rec2 ();
}

void
rec3 ()
{
  int tmp[100];

  k++;
  if (k % MOD == 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k / MOD);
  rec3 ();
}

void
rec4 ()
{
  global[k] = k;
  if (k % 200 == 0)
    fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k);
  k++;
  rec4 ();
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int mode = 1;
  if (argc > 1)
    mode = atoi (argv[1]);

  printf ("Testing rec%d...\n", mode);
  switch (mode)
    {
    case 1:
      rec1 ();
      break;
    case 2:
      rec2 ();
      break;
    case 3:
      rec3 ();
      break;
    case 4:
      rec4 ();
      break;
    default:
      panic ("Wrong mode");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the output when I run the compiled C program in terminal.

```
Testing rec1...
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554904 in rec1 () at stack.c:24
24    rec1 ();

Testing rec2...
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a7b96a in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x555555757670) at malloc.c:3086
3086    malloc.c: No existe el archivo o el directorio.

Testing rec3...
1 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554a43 in rec3 () at stack.c:53
53    rec3 ();

Testing rec4...
0 200 400 600 800 1000 1200 1400 1600 1800 2000 2200 2400 2600 2800 3000 3200 3400 3600 3800 4000 Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555554a1f in rec4 ()
```

Comment: I don't see a `main()` to know how `rec1()` or `rec2()` are called.  I don't know what `k` is.  I do see recursive functions that are probably blowing your stack.  Generally, when you crash, you open it the program in a debugger and examine the final state of the program.  This, with practice, tells you why a program crashed.

Comment: they crash because you didn't compile optimization enabled. Both are optimizable to tail calls that don't leak memory

Comment: Do you know what the name of this site means?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Any program that requires optimization to work scare the hell out of me :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Actually it is funny. This code does not contain UB *per se* as far as I can tell, but still is depending on the optimization. Maybe I am missing something though..

Comment: I honestly don't understand how the compiler saves that code in optimization.   Neither has an obvious exit condition and `k` I assume is a global that cannot be strength reduced to allow the compiler to unroll the loop.  Guess I should godbolt it and see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Do you understand how tail-recursions optimized in general?

Comment: I do - I need more coffee.  Godbolt cleared it up for me.  shit...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan hmm, GCC doesn't optimize the malloc away, while Clang does :( Seems that one needs to remove the NULL check from GCC for that ;)

Comment: I had to say that im starting with programming and its my first post. Anyway, thx for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

The Code that you have is very likely to trigger an error in my experience. Without any compiler or program feedback, it's a little difficult to discern exactly what went wrong, but I believe you may be looking (Generally) for information regarding stacks, heaps, and recursion.

Firstly, please note that

```
void rec1 ()  {
     k++;
     if (k % MOD == 0)
        fprintf (stderr, "%d ", k / MOD);

     rec1 ();
}
```

is **NOT** "Iteration". *Iteration* refers to the repetition of a sequential portion of code (usually a `for` or `while` loop). What you have here is *recursion*. **Recursion** creates a new instance of the method to operate from, along with a *stack pointer* to navigate to the last execution point (As well as store any immediately relevant variables). This occurs every time you call the `rec1 ()` function from your `rec1 ()` function Eventually, you'll run out of space on the stack to store those pointers. The number of pointers you can store on a stack is usually quite large on modern computers, but considering that you have no `return` statement, you will run into the maximum capacity eventually.

**EDIT**

This post has been edited to reflect the new material presented by the question.

Okay...From the material you presented, it looks like you're essentially being asked about WHERE each `rec` stores and processes information...

In the case of `Rec1`, it does indeed appear to be a simple case of stack overflow. The pointer to the last execution point of the previous Rec1 is stored on the stack, ultimately resulting in the program's crash after about 520,000 instances. Given that each pointer is 4 bytes, that's around 2 MB of just recursive pointer information alone stored on your stack before it collapses and triggers a Seg Fault due to stack overflow.

The second case is a little trickier. Note that your program indicates that it makes it to roughly 260,000 recursions before it triggers a Seg Fault. This is exactly half of Rec1. **HOWEVER**, this is not necessarily a stack overflow per se. Rec2 allocates 400 bytes of data on the heap per recursion. The pointer to the heap is stored on the stack, meaning that 8 bytes are stored on the stack per recursion (which **may** be related to why its exactly half, but could also be explained by the ratio of your stack / heap size). Now, the error for Rec2 states that `malloc` could not find the file or directory, which seems to me as though malloc could not complete correctly. This may actually indicate that the max heap size has been hit.

`Rec3` is pretty straightforward. The entire integer array tmp is stored on the stack for each recursion. that's 4 bytes per integer times 100 ints, which is 400 bytes on the stack PER recursion. This is no surprise that it crashes between 10,000 to 20,000 recursions. There just wasn't enough space to store the data on the stack. **NOTE**: In relation to something you mentioned in your question, this tmp array does not attempt to allocate the same region of memory. Due to the fact that this is recursively built, it creates a new space on the stack for that function instance.

`Rec4` is a simple case of buffer overflow. After overwriting the first 100 bytes of memory allocated in `global[100],` it was only a matter of time before `k++` would cause `global[k]` to point to an address space restricted to the process. This triggered the seg fault after about 4000 recursions (k was not mod 10,000 in `rec4`).

I hope this clarification helps.

Comment: It is not *at all* guaranteed to trigger error. There is nothing in the C standard that says "infinite recursion must crash your program". In fact, even `rec2` [compiled with Clang and -O3](https://godbolt.org/) neither leaks memory nor does crash

Comment: Ok, now it is better ;)

Comment: I should have added more information @armitus. The leak is caused in a Virtual ubuntu machine compiling with gcc and runing with gbd. Anyway, this is the output

Comment: @armitus Thankyou for this information. I've been "playing" with the stack size in ubuntu to see if it would affect the execution of those programs and indeed it does.